# Limited resolution options for external monitor

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, display, resolution

Ubuntu will only allow 1024x768 or 800x600 resolution options for my external monitor, an HP 2159m (which supports 1920x1080). The laptop's built-in monitor works fine. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04, and I'm new to Ubuntu.

I've check the HP site, but they only have Windows drivers for this monitor. If it's any help, my laptop also has Windows 8 installed and the external monitor works correctly in 1920x1080 with the generic windows driver.

Any help appreciated! Just let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Have you installed the proprietary drivers for your graphics adapter?

Comment: do you have nvidia-graphics-card ? there are some special new packages out since May.

Comment: I think my laptop has a built in Intel HD Graphics 4000 (that's what Windows say). In ubuntu I found this: adam@Adam-ThinkPad-T430:~$ lspci -v | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])      From Googling it, I've seen that the drivers ought to already be installed by default. Is that correct? Or do I need to install them somehow?